# How to connect my Ubuntu 18.04 to TV by HDMI

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I tried to connect my PC to TV by HDMI but it does not work. Ubuntu does not even connect or read the HDMI, when I connect the wire, nothing changes! 
I installed Nvidia X Server but again it does not work.

Comment: Can you check if it works from you device to another screen? I've never had to do anything when connecting a new screen for a while now. Ubuntu picks it up and it "just works".

Comment: I dont mean pc sorry, I have toshiba all in one pc so I dont need to connect it with any screen because it already there, however I cant connect it to tv by hdmi wire !

Comment: What is your exact Toshiba model number?

Answer (score -3):

I also had this problem. I tried everything and nothing worked, until I changed the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. Run these commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Select and use the Enter key to click *Accept* as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Then select lightdm as the default login display manager as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

And that's it, reboot and go. If your login display manager is modified according to your preferences, there is also a program for Ubuntu to customize it [LightDM GTK + Greeter Settings](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/configure-tela-de-login-com-o-lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings/).